# Declare header in row 4

Tags: import, sas

I want to import a dataset that has headers starting in row 4 and data starting in row 5. The data row is fine, which I have declared. The issue is getting headers when importing the xlsx file. It reads the first row as headers, when headers are in row 4.

```
proc import datafile= "&path\Countries_Data.xlsx"
dbms=xlsx 
out=data replace;
sheet=Data;
Datarow=5;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are importing from a `.xlsx` file, you can use the `range` argument to import specific row/columns from the input file:

```
proc import out = want datafile='c:\temp\have.xlsx'
dbms=xlsx replace;
range="'Data - Groups'$A4 : O12";
GETNAMES=YES;
run;
```

This seems to be the only solution, according to [this source](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/variable-names-in-quot-row-2-quot-how-to-let-PROC-IMPORT-to/td-p/68009). Apparently, SAS does not have an option to declare from which record to pick up the headers when reading other types of files:

> *If your variable names are not on row 1, then you will need to use the GETNAMES=NO and DATAROW=n where n is the starting record of your data. Here is an example of skipping the first rows of data and reading data starting from row 5 while SAS assigns the variable names as VARn where n is a number:*

```
proc import datafile='c:\temp\have.csv' out=class dbms=csv replace;
getnames=no;
datarow=5;
run;
```

Probably, the easiest solution is to fix the source file: delete the first 3 rows and then import to SAS.